# click Control Panel>AdministrativeTools>Services but receiving Event Viewer

Tags: windows-server-2003, 64-bit

I have a W2k3 server (x64 sp2) with which is currently has all updates.  This server runs as a VM.

When I attempt to open the Services MMC by clicking:
 Control Panel>AdministrativeTools>Services
I get the event viewer instead.  I seem to have no method of opening the Services MMC.  (I am logged in as administrator).

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps relevant, I can open the services mmc by going to c:\windows\system32\services.msc   ... adequate workaround for my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Administrative Tools** is simply a shell folder with a bunch of editable shortcuts. The shortcut pointing to **Services** was probably modified.

Right click on the **Services** shortcut, open the properties window, and make sure that is has the following settings:

> **Target:** `%windir%\system32\services.msc`
>
> **Start in:** `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`